# What is the right way to ship a CDT C/C++ project?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have been working with a couple of C/C++ projects in Eclipse CDT and was wondering whether I should include the `Debug/` or `Release/` directories so people who fork my repository can build it ?

I'm asking because I am unsure about it since Eclipse automatically adds these directories to my git ignore file.

Any insights on best practice?

Comment: I am providing this software Open Source on github ans people need to build it from source.

Comment: *..so people who fork my repository can build it..* - They need the sources and the makefile.

Comment: Does CDT not (re-)create those directories when you build?

Comment: Well, it does @HighCommander4 but that's not the point. I think I will simply add the release and debug folders to my repository with instructions on how to build in either configuration.